# call to .save() on domain class fails with no signature of method .save() in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 1.3.2 in NetBeans. I have a very simple unit test that fails with this error:

> No signature of method: com.maxrecall.maxrequire.domain.Release.save()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values:
>   [[flush:true]] Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long),
>   isCase(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), sleep(long)

The relevant code is:

```
Release rel = new Release()
...
rel.save(flush:true)
```

The same code works in BootStrap.groovy. I have tried various variations on .save() (.Save with and without parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a unit test, so there's no Spring, Hibernate, etc. You have to mock the behavior you want.

If you're testing persistence, you need to convert the test to an integration test, since testing persistence with unit tests just tests the mocking framework. An integration test uses at a minimum an in-memory database, although you can easily switch that for a test instance of MySQL/Oracle/etc.

If you're testing controllers or other users of your domain classes and just want them to work so you can focus on testing the current class, use mockDomain and the other mock methods available in the Grails unit test base classes.

This is all described in detail in the documentation - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html

Answer (score 2):

There's no grails magic around in a *unit* test (it's there in an integration test). See "Understanding mockDomain()" [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails10209/index.html) or read the [Grails docs](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing).